# How do you check someone's connection in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

I was having a meetup with my friends, and one of them kept on saying that they were lagging, and left the game, but I'm not convinced, because they literally used that excuse to play Bedwars on Hypixel, which is probably even more lag-prone.

How do I check the connection of someone in Minecraft, to see if it is good or not?

Comment: Can you tell me what's so bad about this question?

Comment: Well I am not good in internals of minecraft, but on pressing tab usually if the connection strength is low, it is likely that they are lagging. I think however the only reliable way is for your friends to screen record their lag and send it to you.

Comment: Ask for their ping, and if it is over 100ms then they are most likely lagging, but anything close to that is also laggy.

Comment: I believe the badlion client does have a way to see another player's ping. Although I have not done any research on it or have tested it out myself.

Comment: I'd say that over 100ms is pretty normal on Hypixel, and it's totally playable. I wouldn't consider that lagging, it's just not the best.

Comment: The OP is asking how to check the connection (quality) from within Minecraft. The scenario they sketch points out that they don't trust the other user, so asking for their ping would probably not be of any use.